# Laravel "composer install" suddenly returns "An option shortcut cannot be empty."

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have been working on a Laravel 7 project since a while. Suddenly, my `composer install` returns the following error

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Modules\Tests\ThumbnailTest located in ./Modules/Media/Tests/ThumbnailTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
                                       
  An option shortcut cannot be empty.                                     

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Laravel version: 7.2
php 7.2
OS: Ubuntu

I have made thousands of installs, and now this error is holding up my project.

The below is stack trace of the error

```
[2024-02-01 08:39:00] local.ERROR: An option shortcut cannot be empty. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): An option shortcut cannot be empty. at /home/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Input/InputOption.php:85)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(459): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\InputOption->__construct()
#1 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/HasParameters.php(32): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->addOption()
#2 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(85): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->specifyParameters()
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Console\\Command->__construct()
#4 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(849): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#5 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(691): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#6 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#7 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(637): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#8 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#9 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#10 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(275): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolve()
#11 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(333): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolveCommands()
#12 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(152): Illuminate\\Support\\ServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Support\\{closure}()
#13 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(75): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->bootstrap()
#14 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(330): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->__construct()
#15 /home/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->getArtisan()
#16 /home/myproject/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#17 {main}
"}
```

All my artisan commands return the same error: "An option shortcut cannot be empty"

Recently, I upgraded to Laravel 7. I have followed the upgrade guide. But this error stack is not giving me any hint where the problem lies.

Comment: There has been a development in this symfony thread https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1728 relating to this issue. Please advise

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to Composer itself? What happens if you run the command seperately?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that both PHP 7.2 and Laravel 7.2 are EOL since years and should no longer be in use in any production system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this happens because of a change in the latest release of `symfony/console`, and a new version that reverts this change should be [released shortly (but not immediately)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/53711#issuecomment-1921340193), you can simply tell composer to avoid installing this particular version.

In this case, add the following to your `composer.json`:

```json
"conflict": {
    "symfony/console": "5.4.35"
  }
```

(If you already have a `conflict` key in there, just add the `symfony/console` line).

With this, this specific version of the library will be skipped on `update`/`install` commands.

(Also, to be noted, the only way for this to become a breaking change is for one to `update` an existing project, or create a project from scratch; `install`ing an existing project should result on reading the lockfile, which should have the previously installed, working version).

Comment: This worked for me. Follow up discussion is in the following links.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/53711
https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1728

Thanks all.

Comment: confirmed this worked for me too, for v8 use a specific version ie "nwidart/laravel-modules": "8.3"

Comment: @Dave I don't think it should be necessary to "conflict" both packages. One could upgrade one, but avoid the root cause which is the `symfony/console` release, right? Why suddenly skip a `laravel/modules` package that was released two years ago?

Comment: the problem happened on both 7 & 8 I believe. I mean one should really upgrade anyway since they are no longer supported. But I know its not always possible to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

It is due to recent change of Symfony framework and issue is occurring in laravel-modules package.
Fix has been done in Both but we need to wait either one to release it.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/53711
https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1728

Comment: Jaymin, no need to wait for a new release. Simply skip the conflicting version by defining a conflict in your `composer.json` file. See my answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77920770/1426539

Answer (score -2):

1. check psr-4 mapping your composer.json file.
2. correct that and delete composer.lock file
3. then run composer install

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this error originates from the code written by the OP?